# Eloquent Bulk insert in MySQL using firstOrCreate function?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, bulkinsert

How could I bulk insert in MySQL using firstOrCreate function on Laravel? I am sending data through RESTfull API

My Model:

```
{
    "hashtags": [{
            "text": "hashtag1"
        }, {
            "text": "hashtag2"
        }, {
            "text": "hashtag3"
        }, {
            "text": "hashtag4"
        }, {
            "text": "hashtag5"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I pass this model to firstOrCreate function,

```
$hashtag_data = $request->get('hashtags');
$hashtags = Hashtag::firstOrCreate($hashtag_data);
```

It returns error.

But When I pass a specific record

```
$hashtag_data = $request->get('hashtags');
$hashtags = Hashtag::firstOrCreate($hashtag_data[1]);
```

It inserts successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work,, not at a machine to test though.

```
   $hashtag_data = $request->get('hashtags');
   $hashtags = Hashtag::insert($hashtag_data);
```

Comment: Yes I have tested such thing. It works but my requirement is that I need all the inserted Ids in return. And Also I need to add only those hashtags that are not in DB.

Comment: @NahyanBinKhalid Having the same final, do you have any solution found so far? I'm working with over 10k records and can't seem to find a decent solution.